# Wordpress Query on custom fields

Tags: wordpress

My site has woocommerce plugin, so post_type is product. Each product has several custom fields used by another plugin (Compare Products Pro).

Now we would like to query products by URL so eg: www.domain.com/?post_type=product&custom_field=value

Is this possible? And how?

Any help would be highly appriciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Building a query based on the `$_GET` variables? Or querying posts based on a custom field?

Comment: So one of the custom fields is brands. I know this rather be a taxonomy, but we had to compare to brands to, hance the custom fields. Now we want to query via url so if we want a list with al the 'honda' products, I would like be able to query this like this: www.domain.com/?post_type=products&_woo_compare_field-15=Honda

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to your query arguments:

```
'post_type' => $_GET['post_type'],
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
       'key' => '_woo_compare_field-',
       'value' => $_GET['_woo_compare_field-'],
       'compare' => '=',
    )

),
```

But its very static, will not work for different meta key value pairs.

You could assign them to an array and append that array like this

```
    $meta_queries = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    );

    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $result = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'value' => $value,
            'compare' => '=',
        );
        $meta_queries[] = $result;
    }
```

And append the `$meta_queries` array to the wordpress query arguments.

But this means all your get variables are used as meta key value pairs. You can ofcourse write some logic for this but it will never be pretty